# How to verify selected radio button (multiple choice) for a qustion is correct or not after form submission in Laravel

Tags: laravel, input, radio-button

Here is my test.blade.php file code

```
<p>(Q.No.1) 15/3+5=? </p> <form method="post"action={{url('testss/result')}}>
{{ csrf_field() }} 
  @foreach($choices as $choice)
   <br>
   <label class="radio-inline">
    <input type="radio" name="1" value="{{$choice['id']}}">
        {{$choice['choice']}}
   </label>
  @endforeach
  <br>
<input type="submit" value="Submit"/>
</form>
```

Here is Schema for choice table Here is 'is_correct' is 1 for correct choice and 0 for wrong choice

```
Schema::create('choices', function (Blueprint $table) {

        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('is_correct');
        $table->string('choice');
        $table->timestamps();}`
```

Here is routes

```
Route::get('/testss/test','TestController@showTest'); Route::post('/testss/result','TestController@showResult');
```

Here is TestController.php

```
class TestController extends Controller{
public function showTest()
{
return View::make('testss.test')
    ->with('choices', Choice::all()); 
}
 public function showResult()
{   echo 'You entered into result page'; $fields = Input::get('choice');
    if($fields['is_correct'] == '1'){
    // logic
    echo 'correct choice you selected';
    }
    else{
    // logic
    echo ''correct choice you selected'';
        }           
return View::make('testss.result')
        ->with('choices', Choice::all());  
        }}
```

Here is choice table

```
Choice_ID   Is_Correct  Choice
1          1         10
2          0          8
3          0          9
4          0          12
```

Here is choice model Choice.php

class Choice extends Model
{
protected $fillable = 
['id','is_correct','choice'];
}

please help me how to display the selected choice is correct or wrong in result.blade.php after clicking submit button in test.blade.php..... choice['id'] is 1,2,3,4 for four multiple choices.

In result.blade.php if selected choice is correct it should echo with correct choice you selected otherwise wrong choice you selected

It is working upto public function showResult()
{   echo 'You entered into result page';

Comment: Obviously, you have to compare the submitted with is_correct. If both are same, then you can change the color of given choice to green else to red.

Comment: Please help me how to write code to get the value from form submitted in test.blade.php and compare it with whether is correct choice or not

Comment: This platform is for helping the developers with their errors, bugs and logical problem. You have to write your code and then if you face an error or you are stuck, then you can come back to the community for help.